# Noob Problems with PHP Script for My Form

Tags: php, forms

Thank you in advance to all:

When I test the form page it loads with an error "undefined variable lines...." for $myname and $email corresponding to the first four if/else  statements.

When I move the first endif to the bottom of the script the undefined variables go away, but then the error messages no longer show up when I don't fill out the form properly, and the "Thanks for filling out the form" message no longer shows up when I do :(

Also, when I have the first endif at the top the error messages "Your name must be in the format: Last, first" and "your email must be in the proper format" are already present before I even touch the form.

Ok so this is the form and PHP script that I have on a separate file:

```
<?php if (isset($msg)) { echo '<div id = "thanks"/><p>', $msg , '</p></div>'; } ?>
<form id="myform" name="theform" class="group" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">

<span id="firstname"> Name (Last, First):</span> <span id="firstnamefield">
<input type="text" name="myname" size="50" value:"<?php if (isset($myname)) {echo $myname;} ?>"/></span>
<?php if (isset($err_myname)) { echo '<div id = "error"/><p>', $err_myname , '</p></div>'; } ?>
<?php if (isset($err_namematch)) { echo '<div id = "namematch"/><p>', $err_namematch , '</p></div>'; } ?>


<span id="mail">Email:</span> <span id="emailfield"><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) {echo $email;} ?>"/></span>
<?php if (isset($err_email)) { echo '<div id = "emailerror"/><p>', $err_email , '</p></div>'; } ?>
<?php if (isset($err_patternmatch)) { echo '<div id = "emailmatch"/><p>', $err_patternmatch , '</p></div>'; } ?>


<span id="telephone">Phone:</span><span id="phonefield"><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php if (isset($phone)) {echo $phone;} ?>"/></span>


<span id="sub"><input type="image" name="action" value="submit"   src="images/submit.png" alt="Submit" /></span>

</form>
```

This is what I have on my PHP file:

```
<?php 
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))): 

endif; //form submitted   

    if (isset($_POST['myname'])) { $myname = $_POST['myname']; } 
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; }  
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; }  


    $formerrors = false;

    if ($myname ===''):
      $err_myname = "*Sorry, your name is a required field";
      $formerrors = true;
    endif; //Input Field Empty


    if ($email ===''):
      $err_email = "*Sorry, your email is a required field";
      $formerrors = true;
    endif; //Input Field Empty



   if ( !(preg_match('/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a- zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/', $email)) ):
     $err_patternmatch = "*Your email must be in the correct format";
     $formerrors = true;
   endif; //Input Must Match Proper Format



   if ( !(preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+, [A-Za-z]+/', $myname))):
     $err_namematch = "*Your name must be in the format: Last, First";
     $formerrors =true;
   endif; //Input Must Match Proper Format


   if (!($formerrors)):
     $to  =  "test1234@yahoo.com"; 
     $subject  =  "From $myname --Postcard Landing Page";
     $message  = "You have a new lead.";

     $replyto  =  "From: $email \r\n".
             "Reply-To: donotreply@domain.com \r\n";

    if (mail($to,$subject,$message)):
         $msg = "Thank you for filling out the form!";
    else:
         $msg =  "Problem sending message";
    endif; // mail form data                    

    endif; // Check for For Errors



?>
```

Comment: Put a `var_dump($_POST['myname']);die();` statement just before the three if's in the PHP code, and check what it outputs. Also, currently the first if/endif doesn't make sense, since you're checking something and doing nothing afterwards.

Comment: @user2196728 There's an alternative syntax for control structures, [check it out](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). It's often used in template pages.

Comment: ok, great, i admit i don't like to deal with alternative coding but more "pure" coding, so i will never code php this way...but nevermind ;)

Comment: @NorthBridge Yeah the first end if....I put it that way only cause it was the only way to get the error messages to show up when I don't fill out the form correctly. If I put it at the end of the entire script then none of the error messages show up, but the unidentified variable error goes away :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part:

```
if (isset($_POST['myname'])) { $myname = $_POST['myname']; } 
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; }  
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; }
```

You are setting the variables only if these values are set. Now, in case of invalid form submission, the code execution does not happen inside the if block and continues to the next part without your variables being set.

Here's how you can fix it. Initialize all variables to '' in the beginning of the script before you read the $_POST values:

```
$myname = ''
$phone = ''
$email = ''
```

Comment: Hi thanks gat...That got rid of the unidentified variable problem :) I put them before if (isset($_POST['myname'])) { $myname = $_POST['myname']; } 
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; }  
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; }

Comment: Now all my error messages (name required etc.) are showing up before I even fill out the form. Any suggestions?

Comment: One way to fix this would be to add a hidden field on the form. eg. <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="true">. Now you may first check whether it has been set in $_POST before executing the form handling part of your script.